# How can i restrict users access to their OneDrive account in office365 without disabling license?

Tags: azure, office365, onedrive

How can i restrict users access to their  OneDrive account in office365 without disabling license?

Comment: Care to provide a bit more background than just repeating your title in the question body? As in: WHY? OneDrive is meant to be the place where users store files. Why do you want to restrict that?

Comment: Thank you for response. In this time in our organization many users( 1000+) has OneDrive Access. But i whant to create a security group for manually adding users who would access OneDrive. before that i must disable all users access and then add for these users what are neccessary.

Comment: Problem resolved with  Azure Conditional Access.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Conditional Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/overview) to disable access to OneDrive for everyone who is not a member of a certain security group.

From an implementation standpoint I would not recommend this approach though as your users will still see OneDrive and SharePoint in all their apps and webportal, but get an error when they are trying to connect. Which will likely confuse them.

While you say you don't want to disable the licenses, you could use [group based licensing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-licensing-whatis-azure-portal) in Azure AD. This not only allows you to assign licenses to users based on group memberships automatically, but also select which features of a given license should be enabled for members of this group.

When a user needs a license simply switch from one group with OneDrive Disabled to the other with OneDrive enabled. This will give your users a better experience until you actually enable OneDrive for them.